# How does google crawl and index your content after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, seo

Let's say we have this code

```
<body>
  content-1
</body>

<script>
  setTimeout(changeBodyContentTo("content-2"), 5000);
</script>
```

In this case will google crawl and index content-1 or content-2? and how we can test that?

Comment: I voted to close this question because general SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.